# Kubuntu crashes upon sleep on Surface Laptop

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, sleep, kubuntu, microsoft-surface

I'm running Kubuntu 23.10 on my Surface Laptop 3, and when I sleep the computer, instead of going fully black, it goes black and just shows my cursor, but I can't move it. In order to get back into my computer, I have to hold the power button to shut down my computer. I installed Kubuntu recently, and I also have windows 11 dual boot. From all of the solutions I've looked at, it seems it could be a problem with graphics card/driver(I have Mesa Intel Iris Plus Graphics).

Thanks in advance.